# Exclude dependencies

Tags: gradle

I want to exclude dependencies from a dependency :

```
dependencies {
...
    implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:$springSecurityVersion" {

        exclude "org.springframework:spring-core:$springSecurityVersion"
        exclude "org.springframework:spring-beans:$springSecurityVersion"
        exclude "org.springframework:spring-context:$springSecurityVersion"
        exclude "org.springframework:spring-web:$springSecurityVersion"
    }
...
}
```

I tried a couple of options by changing the syntax sugar but in vain.

**Updated Exception** :

```
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-bin.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:51)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsume
...
```

Apart from that one more line that I see that could be useful is

> Could not find method
>   org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:5.0.4.RELEASE() for
>   arguments
>   [build_8wp04892dra2g2ruliafngaad$_run_closure3$_closure5@28d49bbc] on
>   object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this syntax, without specifying the version :

```
implementation ("org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:$springSecurityVersion") {
    exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-core'
    exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-beans'
    exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-context'
    exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-web'
}
```

edit : Delete your `.gradle` directory in your home directory and try again

edit2 : answer's fixed, thanks to op's comment

Comment: Still fails. Also tried `exclude group: "org.springframework:spring-core"` does not work

Comment: added the exception in my question

Comment: Same error also deleted bin, build and .gradle folders still same issue.

Comment: My issue was resolved by changing my first line to `implementation ("org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:$springSecurityVersion")`

Comment: Missing parenthesis, indeed